# Cannot get Open Accessory Development Kit working on Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android

I got an Arduino MEGA ADK board and a Samsung galaxy nexus phone.
I managed to upload the demokit progam to both the board and phone without errors.
However, there is no response when I connect them, the app on phone still shows the "Please connect a Demokit board" screen. Have anyone got it working on Galaxy Nexus yet?
I tried using both the 2.3.4+ and 3.1+ libraries (com.android.future.usb and android.hardware.usb), both can be successfully compiled and install into the phone, but both shows no response when I plug-in the usb port.
And is there some newer documents of demo for the ADK? The original demokit code is so out-dated that it's not even compatible with Arduino 1.0...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it working on a Galaxy Nexus with an Arduino Mega ADK. Quick data,

- DemoKit targeted with Google APIs 2.3.3 level 10 as-is (NOT Android 2.3.3), no changes in
  code.
- Arduino firmware from
  http://www.bdgcustoms.com/diy_android_adk.html compiled and uploaded with Arduino 
  0022
- Connect the Nexus with ADK board and reset the ADK board

I have not looked into it in detail, but the Arduino firmware in the DemoKit communicates with a joystick using the Wire library. In the setup() the joystick is initialized, init_joystick(), and the firmware might get blocked if there is no joystick connected. So, for a bare Arduino Mega ADK the original firmware code has to be modified. For me it worked with the firmware in the link above.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, the joystick initialization is the problem!